# How can I get the function name in the shared library with an address from backtrace_symbols?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I try to print the call stack in some functions by using "backtrace" and "backtrace_symbols".
But the app builded without -rdynamic. So the output of backtrace_symbols show just like this:
     libnet.so [0x1a08f36]
Then who can tell me how can I get the function name by 0x1a08f36?